# Is llvmlite dependent on LLVM version or pip version?

Tags: python, llvm, numba, librosa, llvmlite

This Question might sound strange ! But this is my observation. 
I'm currently using Debian wheezy , it initially had python-pip 1.1 version. installing llvmlite with the above pip version requested for a LLVM_CONFIG path , Compatible versions of LLVM for llvmlite - were not available in the default repository of debian wheezy sources.list. So i could not install  llvmlite.

Later point i upgraded pip version to 18.1 and tried to reinstall llvmlite using llvmlite. Now it did not prompt for any LLVM_CONFIG file (and got successfully installed). And i don't see any library related to LLVM installed in my system ? 
What has happened here ?
FYI :: I had to install llvmlite as it is a hard dependency of librosa -> numba

Answer (score 1):

It seems you originally had a quite old version of pip installed (https://pypi.org/project/pip/#history) that didn't support wheels (binary packages).  It would have likely tried to build from source, which needs an LLVM version to statically link against.

With a newer pip, the wheel can be used, which already has LLVM statically linked.  See the llvmlite docs here for more details.

https://llvmlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin-guide/install.html#why-static

Comment: Can u brief what static linking is ? How does llvmlite get configured without availability of LLVM  in the OS?

Comment: Can i summarise it like , required parts of LLVM for llvmlite were integrated with newer versions of llvmlite ? Avoiding unused parts of LLVM

Comment: That's right - required bits of LLVM are embedded into the llvmlite binary